# Trouble increasing sample size for power analysis in simr

Tags: r, simulation

I want to increase the sample size being considering in a power analysis I'm running using simr. With my pilot data of 5 participants, I am able to run the power analysis, but when I use the extend function to increase the number of subjects to 20, I am getting: Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable): unable to find an inherited method for function ‘extend’ for signature ‘"lmerModLmerTest"’. The extend function does not seem to be working on my model.

I get the same error using the following code, taken from an example online:

```
#load in the data
sleep_df = lme4::sleepstudy %>% 
  clean_names()

#set up the model
y_var = "reaction"
fixed_effect = "days"
random_effect = "subject"
model_form = as.formula(paste0(y_var, " ~ ", fixed_effect, " + ", "(1|", random_effect, ")"))
print(model_form)

#run simulation
set.seed(1)
sleep_fit = lmer(model_form, 
                 data = sleep_df)
model_form2 <- extend(sleep_fit, along="subject", n=20)
model_form2
```

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

At the top of my head, I can think of two possible errors:

1. Your `subject` variable is not specified as an integer, but as a factor. `extend()` only works on linear variables. However, since you reproduce the error with an example known to work, I think we can disregard this.
2. The problem is not with the data, but with your R session. For example, if you load after `simr` another package that has a function that is also named `extend()` then the function `simr::extend()` will be masked by the second one. This should show up when you load the package, a message like `The following object is masked from 'package:simr'` would be printed in the terminal. To solve this, either specify `simr::extend()` when you want to use this function, or change the order in which you load your packages.

Hope that helps somehow.